# How do I define df.iloc[:,:-1] properly without getting any error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am training my data by using multiclass SVM, and this is my [reference](https://github.com/ShanmukhVegi/Image-Classification/blob/main/Shanmukh_Classification.ipynb). Whenever I try to run the line below, it gives me a memory error. How do I assign `df.iloc[:,:-1]` to a variable without getting any error?

```
x=df.iloc[:,:-1]
```

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Here's the error: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.60 GiB for an array with shape (11126, 67500) and data type float64

Comment: The first line copies all but the last column of df, and there's not enough space in your memory to do that. In the link you provided there's only 100 images, while it looks like you have 11126. Could you run the code with a reduced set of images?

Comment: I see. I'll try it again with a reduced dataset. I'll inform regarding the status again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
x = df
y = x.pop(x.columns[-1])
```

This will set `x` to be a reference to `df`, then cause the rightmost column of `df` (with contents equivalent to `df.iloc[:,-1]`) to be assigned to `y` and deleted from `x`.

In the pandas source, [`pop()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/87cfe4e38bafe7300a6003a1d18bd80f3f77c763/pandas/core/generic.py#L921) is equivalent to:

```py
item = x.columns[-1]
y = x[item]
del x[item]
```

Because `del` is an in-place operation, `pop()` should not attempt to make a copy of the input dataframe before mutating it. This may be less memory intensive than OP's code.

Note that the 5.6 GB size of `df` shown in OP's comment also suggests it may be prudent to try to modify program logic to partition the input and process it in smaller batches.

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question?